# Can I somehow query all the existing tables in peewee / postgres?

Tags: python, peewee

I am writing a basic gui for a program which uses Peewee. In the gui, I would like to show all the tables which exist in my database.

Is there any way to get the names of all existing tables, lets say in a list?

Comment: If you already have your connection established, run `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'` to get the table names in your schema. That should return a list of 1-element tuples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Peewee has the ability to introspect Postgres, MySQL and SQLite for the following types of schema information:

- Table names
- Columns (name, data type, null?, primary key?, table)
- Primary keys (column(s))
- Foreign keys (column, dest table, dest column, table)
- Indexes (name, sql*, columns, unique?, table)

You can get this metadata using the following methods on the `Database` class:

- [Database.get_tables()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=get_tables#Database.get_tables)
- [Database.get_columns()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=get_columns#Database.get_columns)
- [Database.get_indexes()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=get_indexes#Database.get_indexes)
- [Database.get_primary_keys()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=get_primary_keys#Database.get_primary_keys)
- [Database.get_foreign_keys()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=get_foreign_keys#Database.get_foreign_keys)

So, instead of using a cursor and writing some SQL yourself, just do:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase('my_db')
tables = db.get_tables()
```

For even more craziness, check out the [reflection](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#reflection) module, which can actually generate Peewee model classes from an existing database schema.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the tables in your schema, make sure that you have established your connection and cursor and try the following:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public'")
myables = cursor.fetchall()
mytables = [x[0] for x in mytables]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is really not the best way to do this with Peewee. Much better would be to use the "database.get_tables()" function.

Comment: @coleifer I understand the change of answers but what's with the downvote?